# Existence of matrix of size NxN with following properties

Tags: matrices, algorithms, systems-of-equations

You are given an integer $N$. ($N \le 100$). Does there exists a matrix $A$ of size $N\times N$ with the following properties?

- Each element of $A$ is either 1 or -1.
- The sum of products of corresponding elements of any two rows is zero. i.e. for any $1 \le i < j \le N$ 
  $$ \sum_{k=1}^N A_{i,k}A_{j,k} = 0. $$ 
  ( I am considering 1 based indexing here)

What I have done: I have tried a brute force solution. Each element can either be 1 or -1. so there can be at most $2^{N^2}$ matrices. I tried checking all of these matrices but the algorithm is way too slow. $O(N^2 2^{N^2})$ actually. My computer did not show any output for $N = 5$ and I had to terminate the program. Can anybody suggest a better way to solve this problem?

You have to not only answer Yes or No but enumerate one such matrix too. Obviously when $N$ is odd the answer is not possible. $N = 1$ is a trivial case with answer as 1 or -1.

Comment: you might want to exclude $a=b$

Comment: @user251257 Thanks for pointing out. This is my first question here so I 'm skipping obvious details compulsively.

Comment: I edited your post with the usual TeX formatting. I also changed the indices $a,b$ to more common $i,j$. If you don't like it. I am sorry. Please change them back or revert it.

Comment: I loved it actually. Thank you :)

Comment: No need for a computer for $N=5$ -- for odd $N$, the orthogonality conditions can't be fulfilled because the sums are odd.

Comment: @user251257 Here is one possible solution for N = 4
1 -1 -1 1

-1 1 -1 1

-1 -1 1 1

1 1 1 1

Comment: @lassaendie: I read it wrong. ignore my post.

Comment: @joriki Yup I know that. I just wanted to know what were the algorithms limit.

Comment: It's a minor optimization, but scaling columns by $-1$ as necessary, you may arrange that the first row is all ones.  Thus subsequent rows must have equally many $1$s as $-1$s.

Answer (score 2):

Such matrices are called [Hadamard matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_matrix). As you can read in the section on the [Hadamard conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_matrix#Hadamard_conjecture), the problem of their existence is open. What is known is that if a Hadamard matrix for $N$ exists, then $N$ is $1$, $2$ or a multiple of $4$. The smallest order for which existence is currently unknown is $N=668$.

Since you imposed the constraint $N\le100$, the answer is that a Hadamard matrix exists if and only if $N$ is $1$, $2$ or a multiple of $4$.

Comment: Thank you for that. But I also have to enumerate 1 possible matrix for each N. I have answers for N = 1,2 and 4 and for 8 I solved a partial solution manually.

Comment: @lassaendie: Sorry, I'd overlooked that part. What kind of a crazy exercise is that? They want you to specify a $100\times100$ matrix?! Crazy enough just because of the sheer size of it, but to make things worse, as you can read in the section I linked to, a Hadamard matrix for $N=92$ was only found by computer in $1962$. How on Earth are you supposed to find it, other than just copying it from that paper?

Comment: The original question is not about Hadamard matrices. In fact there is no mention of it. It consisted of a series of equations to assign numbers to to a NxN matrix which resulted in the properties i just mentioned. I never thought I would end up here. I have to use a computer of course. But with a little intuition I reached a partial solution for N = 8. but thanks anyways. I'll just look these matrices up.

Comment: @lassaendie: Eric Tressler (Master's Thesis, 2004, Virginia Tech) wrote [A Survey of the Hadamard Conjecture](http://scholar.lib.vt.edu/theses/available/etd-05042004-120929/unrestricted/thesis_revised.pdf), which describes the well-known construction methods such as taking Kronecker products.